# How to solve base currency with the selling currency

Tags: payment, currency

If the Euro base currency is configured, and frontend to sell in dolar.

The finalization of the cart shows in dollars, but sends the value in euro for means of payments, and there are few means of payment that interprets that the value is in another currency

I wanted to know how to solve this, I did a lot of research, and how even started to work on the core of the magento to send the currency of the frontend and not the base, I did not find anything

Would have a module or some configuration in the source code to build this?

Base currency of the EURO magento, and Dollar frontend, and finalize the order in the same payment in Dollar, the products are bought in euro and suffer the daily change, so i am need a solution, than to change base currency to dollar

Comment: @Enigmativity The audience of Magento here is bigger, and it's programming, there's no solution on the internet =(

Comment: No, Magento is a server-based e-commerce platform, and even though the platform is software it doesn't mean that every question about Magento is programming. Even when you mention "source code" in the question it is still not about programming. Your question should be explicitly about programming.

Comment: Did you try to change **Base Currency** and **Default Display Currency**?

Comment: yes =( @ChristosLytras